# Trackpad software issue after Magic Trackpad update

Tags: macos, mac, laptop, macbook-pro, magic-trackpad

I recently went into Software Update and updated. In there, was the "Magic Trackpad Update" which, I assume, is a software update for the compatibility of Magic Trackpad.

Now, my built-in trackpad is very sensitive and annoying, I had to disable pinch to zoom. Any way of reverting this update? Also, has anyone else been experiencing this?

Answer (score 0):

The update installs a new preference panel which allows you to adjust the sensitivity of the trackpad, and how various gestures are interpreted -- just look in System Preferences.